# Flux through a conduting cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

> *A point charge of magnitude $Q$ is placed inside a conducting cylinder of length $L$ and radius  $R$ at its centre. What is the flux through the cylinder?*

I know that I have to use Gauss Law here but my concern is:

> *Since it is a conducting cylinder, there would be equal and opposite charges induced on its surface. How do I account for these charges?*

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You dont have to they would be equal and opposite on either side of the surface, their flux would also be equal and oppsite, they would simply cancel out by themselves !

Comment: $\phi=q_{enclosed}/\epsilon_0$ $q_{enc}=\sum_i q_i$ so $q_{enc}$ will be $0$, and gauss law also says $\phi=0$ for closed surface. So your assumption is right.

Answer (score 0):

Remember I'm not 100% sure about my answer.

If you consider the gaussian surface just above the surface of the cylinder then the total charge enclosed by your gaussian surface will be Q+ Q (induced)-Q (induced) = Q. So the flux will be 
Q/€°.
 If you consider the gaussian surface in between the outer and inner surfaces of the cylinder (provided the surface of the cylinder is a bit thick) then the total charge enclosed by your gaussian surface will be Q~Q = 0. Therefore the flux is zero.
 I'm not a teacher, I'm a student of 16 year old. If I've made a mistake forgive me. 
Thank you for making me to think a bit.

Comment: To check flux you do not need a gaussian surface, that is required while applying gauss law to calculate electric field.

Comment: But we can use gauss law to calculate the flux. May be you are studying your undergraduate course, you better go back to 12th text book and read gauss law once again. They haven't given that we should not use gauss law to calculate the flux. sorry if I'm rude. ( I'm younger than you, so you have to forgive me if I'm wrong. And correct me.)

Comment: It's ok, I wasn't saying gauss law isn't used to calcuoate flux. I was saying **gausian surface** isn't necessarily requisite to find out net flux through a body it is only required when you use gauss law for further calculations.